# how we can use ajax() in views.py in django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have little code over here.

Can you please explain me that what that code exactly does in details. please.

In script here is the ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
            url : "{% url 'upload_document' %}",
            type: "POST",
            data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken:    document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                    title: document.getElementById('title').value,
                    //document: document: document.getElementById('document'),
            },
            dataType : "json",
            success: function( response ){
               if(response == "True"){
                // success
               }
               else {
                //append errors
               }
            }
          });
```

How ajax is works in django and how can we use ajax request in view.
Here my views
 views.py

```
def upload_document(request): 
    print request.POST
    print request.FILES
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user)

            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps('True'), mimetype = 'application/json' )
            else:
                errors = form.errors
                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(errors), mimetype = 'application/json' )
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "How does Ajax work" is too broad for a question on SO. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to know basic how we can ajax in django. views.py

Comment: And what is wrong with the code that you have?

Comment: The easiest way is to set up a new route, and use some kind of "polling" to query that route (you send some data, in the form of an HTTP request, and the route processes it and sends some back).

Comment: you cant upload files in this way, try [link](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `$.ajax` method sends an asynchronous http request.

You can read about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

First argument is url, where we send request.

Second, is request method it may be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and etc. see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Third argument is key-value dictionary with data, which you use in server-side.
In django, you may access it in request.POST(in case of post request)

Fourth argument is function, which is invoked when server succesfully returns response.
You do not need if statement in this function, because when request fails or server does not give a response, or server returns error(something like `40*` code for example) this function will not be invoked.

This function takes one argument with server's response. You need handling this data, for example showing user a message like `Invalid data, please correct errors...` or `Valid data. your request is in process now.` and staff like that.

Last argument is data type of servers response. jQuery is smart enough to parse json or html for you, so in this case, response(argument of success function) is pure JS object, deserialized from JSON.

In your server-side(Django views) you must do some validation of request's data. and do something with it. For example, save it to database. When i have to implement ajax form processing i do sumething like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    response = {}
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        response['success'] = 1
    else:
        response['success'] = 0
        response['errors'] = dict(form.errors)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response), mimetype = 'application/json' )
```

And on client side, in js something like this

```
$.post('/url/to/view',
       function(json){
           if(json['success']){
               alert('Yahooo! Successfull request')
           }
           else{
               alert('Oooops. Looks like you send invalid data')
           }
       }, 'json')
```

Good luck!